# return a result even if there is no data for that day/ week/ month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an MSSQL database and I want to get a value for each day/ week/ month in separate queries.

I got this working just fine except for intervals where there is no data, it wont return anything. And since im putting this in a graph, I want it to display a 0 or a NULL at least instead of jumping days or weeks etc.

I dont know if it will be different for each query but here is my daily query:

```
select CAST(Placements.CreatedOn AS DATE) AS 
date,SUM(Placements.CommissionPerc * (Placements.PlacementFee / 100)) AS value 
from [placements] 
where [Placements].[CreatedOn] >= '2018-06-07' and [Placements].[CreatedOn] < '2018-06-12' 
group by CAST(Placements.CreatedOn AS DATE) 
order by CAST(Placements.CreatedOn AS DATE) ASC
```

This returns a result like:

[image: result]

So it returns 0 for when the data is actually 0 but when its missing, theres nothing like for days 9, 10 and 12

How can i fix this? thanks

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. I have removed MySQL from the tags; as it seems to be SQL server problem.

Comment: Search for `calendar table`, you'll find many examples.

Comment: Have a calendar table, Outer join.

Comment: This is not my database and i cannot add tables

Comment: You can use a CTE to create the calendar!

Comment: @jarlh so the calander is just in the query and not an actual table?

Comment: Either way. (An actual table is always better. But if you can't, a cte will do fine as well.)

Comment: Well, the benefit of a permant "Calendar" table is that it would be reusable for other queries. And also that such table can contain extra fields that can't be derived via the [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) function.  Just one downside is that ,unless you fill with a century, that sometimes extra years need to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE you can generate a list of dates.
Which can then be used to LEFT JOIN your table.

Example:

```
WITH DATES2018 AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AS [date]

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, [date])
  FROM DATES2018
  WHERE [date] < CAST('2018-12-31' AS DATE)
)
SELECT 
d.[Date],
SUM(p.CommissionPerc * (p.PlacementFee / 100.0)) AS [value] 
FROM DATES2018 AS d
LEFT JOIN [Placements] AS p ON CAST(p.CreatedOn AS DATE) = d.[Date]
WHERE d.[Date] BETWEEN '2018-06-07' AND '2018-06-11' 
GROUP BY d.[Date]
ORDER BY d.[Date] ASC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366)
```

But you could also just add a new permanent table with all dates.
And use that table to left join your table.

Btw, if variables are used for the start and end date then that SQL can be optimized.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-06-07';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2018-06-11';

WITH DATES AS
(
  SELECT @StartDate AS [date]

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, [date])
  FROM DATES
  WHERE [date] < @EndDate
)
SELECT 
d.[Date],
SUM(p.CommissionPerc * (p.PlacementFee / 100.0)) AS [value] 
FROM DATES AS d
LEFT JOIN [Placements] AS p 
  ON p.CreatedOn BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate AS DATETIME) AND CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate) AS DATETIME) AND
     CAST(p.CreatedOn AS DATE) = d.[Date]
GROUP BY d.[Date]
ORDER BY d.[Date] ASC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A permanent calendar table would be best but here's and example that uses a CTE to create the dates needed for a `LEFT JOIN`. This uses a maximum of 1,000 days but can be extended as needed.

```
DECLARE 
      @StartDate date = '2018-06-07'
    , @EndDate date = '2018-06-12';
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1 AS num  FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,calendar AS (SELECT DATEADD(day, num, @StartDate) AS calendar_date
        FROM t1k
        WHERE num <= DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)
        )
SELECT
      calendar.calendar_date AS date
    , SUM( COALESCE(Placements.CommissionPerc * (Placements.PlacementFee / 100),0 ) ) AS value 
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN [placements] ON [Placements].[CreatedOn] = calendar.calendar_date
GROUP BY calendar.calendar_date
ORDER BY calendar.calendar_date ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks very much! the other guy was a couple minutes faster so i had to accept his but really appreciate it

Comment: @WillDaniels, the CTE my answer is not recursive and will run faster than the other solution. Not suggesting you accept mine instead but you should upvote.